# CS1061: Type `string' does not contain a definition for `classChoice' and no extension method `classChoice'

Tags: c#, class, methods, instance

I am trying to return the value of the string classChoice to a separate Class so that I can return the person's selection, I am still learning C# and have tried to understand this better i read that it needs an instance to work so i created 1, either way, i have tried about 8 different ways of doing this and all keep returning errors, what am I doing wrong?

made it a void and failed, took out the argument and tried to call only the property, tried it outside the cs file in the main cs still no luck.

```
public class Selection
{

    public string CharSel(string classChoice = "")
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the world of Text Games!");

        Console.WriteLine("To begin you must select a class!");

        Console.WriteLine("Lucky for you there is only 1 class to choose from at this time :-) ");

        Console.WriteLine("Select a Class:");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Wizard");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Nothing");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Nothing");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Nothing");
        Console.WriteLine("5. Nothing");

        Console.Write("Make your selection: ");

        int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            classChoice = "Wizard";
            Console.WriteLine("Congrats on selecting {0} now onto your adventure!", classChoice);
        }
        return classChoice;
    }
}

public class Character
{
    public static string Wizard(string name)
    {
        Selection s = new Selection();

        string classChosen = s.CharSel().classChoice;
        Console.WriteLine("Test, You are a {0}", classChosen);
        name = "none yet";
        return name;
    }
}
```

Console should spiit out

```
Test, You are a Wizard
```

Comment: As best I can follow, `CharSel` is a merthod not a class, so `s.CharSel().classChoice;` fails because methods do not have properties (and also the only way that would work is if it was static).  You are overthinking it: `CharSel` returns a string representing the choice, use it.

Comment: You need an instance of selection : Selection selection = new Selection();  string classChoice = selection.CharSel("abc");

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp it fails as a static as well I am literally banging my head you may be right I am overthinking it.

Comment: @jdweng isnt Selection s = new Selection(); the same exact thing? and string class Chosen being s.CharSel().classChoice shouldn't that return the choice that was selected previously?

Comment: *You are overthinking it:* `CharSel` *returns a string representing the choice, use it.*

Comment: s.CharSel() is a method that returns a string.  There is not such string property classChoice.  So the error is due to you adding classChoice to the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CharSel()` is a method which returns a `string` containing the value selected by the user.

You returned that `string` at the end of the method so when you call that method it effectively *is* the returned `string` (the value contained in the `classChoice` variable).  That is why is is giving you that error: 'CharSel()' is a `string` and what you have written (`s.CharSel().classChoice`) is attempting to find a `classChoice` method on the `String` class (or an extension method).  Just remove `.classChoice` from the assignment to `classChosen` and it will work as you expect.

Another important point is that `classChoice` is a private variable of the `CharSel()` method and isn't visible outside of the method.

Comment: Thank you I have the solution now @Jaquez  and I managed to bring it back to a static Sorry for the amature question I am building a text game to pratice my console coding abilities with C# and I hit a stone wall I gave it about 8 different ways and read everything I could find on here but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your program on the line:

```
string classChosen = s.CharSel().classChoice;
```

It should be:

```
string classChosen = s.CharSel();
```